# setting up an sql connection to run a spring-mvc project, using intelliJ

Tags: spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I've cloned a spring-mvc project to my computer and trying to get it running using intelliJ. It seems, according to [this](http://pastebin.com/va36Lazr) that I need to establish an SQL connection. Do I need to download mysql to my computer, create an account and enter that information in my connection.XML file (seen below)?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<!--  Data Source Setup -->
<bean id="hsqldataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql" />
    <property name="username" value="example" />
    <property name="password" value="example" />
</bean>
<bean id="mysqldataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.0.0:3306/dev" />
<property name="username" value="example" />
    <property name="password" value="example" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>example/peer-review/domain/hibernatemapping/Division.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>example/peer-review/domain/hibernatemapping/Modality.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>example/peer-review/domain/hibernatemapping/Score.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>example/peer-review/domain/hibernatemapping/User.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>example/peer-review/domain/hibernatemapping/QaCase.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>example/peer-review/domain/hibernatemapping/Review.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>example/peer-review/domain/hibernatemapping/Exam.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>example/peer-review/domain/hibernatemapping/Patient.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>example/peer-review/domain/hibernatemapping/Role.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="hsqldataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<!--  Dao Layer generic config-->    
<bean id="abstractDaoTarget" class="example.peer-review.persistence.hibernate.GenericDAOHibernateImpl" abstract="true">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<!--  Dao Layer instances -->
<bean id="DivisionDAO" parent="abstractDaoTarget" class="example.peer-review.persistence.hibernate.DivisionDAOHibernateImpl" />
<bean id="ModalityDAO" parent="abstractDaoTarget" class="example.peer-review.persistence.hibernate.ModalityDAOHibernateImpl" />
<bean id="ScoreDAO" parent="abstractDaoTarget" class="example.peer-review.persistence.hibernate.ScoreDAOHibernateImpl" />
<bean id="UserDAO" parent="abstractDaoTarget" class="example.peer-review.persistence.hibernate.UserDAOHibernateImpl" />
<bean id="ReviewDAO" parent="abstractDaoTarget" class="example.peer-review.persistence.hibernate.ReviewDAOHibernateImpl" />
<bean id="QaCaseDAO" parent="abstractDaoTarget" class="example.peer-review.persistence.hibernate.QaCaseDAOHibernateImpl" />
<bean id="ExamDAO" parent="abstractDaoTarget" class="example.peer-review.persistence.hibernate.ExamDAOHibernateImpl" />
<bean id="PatientDAO" parent="abstractDaoTarget" class="example.peer-review.persistence.hibernate.PatientDAOHibernateImpl" />
<bean id="RoleDAO" parent="abstractDaoTarget" class="example.peer-review.persistence.hibernate.RoleDAOHibernateImpl" />

<bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
  <property name="url" value="ldap://example.edu:1234" />
  <property name="base" value="" />
  <property name="userDn" value="cn=Test1" />
  <property name="password" value="Test1" />
  <property name="authenticationStrategy" ref="ldapAuthStrat" />
</bean>

<bean id="ldapTemplate" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="ldapAuthStrat" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.ExternalTlsDirContextAuthenticationStrategy" />
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conf file contains the definition for two different datasources, hsql and mysql. hsql is an in memory db.

Mysql is standalone database application.

yes to connect to the mysql source, you need to download mysql and set up users/schema.

Comment: i have mysql loaded but I"m unable to figure out how to connect to it. ![connection image](http://snag.gy/hC9Dt.jpg)

Comment: if I were able to connect using root, I would then be able to use that connection for the mysql db right?

Comment: if you can connect to DB, you can use the same credentials in java yes

Comment: this is embarrassing, I'm unable to figure out how to connect to it. Maybe I should re-install mysql and create a new root account and pw?

Comment: if you don't know how to connect, how will reinstalling help ?

Comment: learn how to connect to mysql on commandline, its this: "mysql -uROOT -pMyPassword"

Comment: yes, I tried that and don't know the password to root. like i said, this is embarrassing

Comment: yes then if you reinstall you can set a new password